# JS | Recurse through nested "for of" Loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, ecmascript-6

While learning NodeJS, I've been battling to write a more concise logic to this code block (see below) that could either introduce **recursion** or make use of **ES6 methods** to provide more elegance and better readability.

I'm bothered by the nesting happening on the `for of loops`

Thoughts?

```
export function pleaseRefactorMe(measures, metrics, stats) {

  if (!Array.isArray(metrics)) metrics = [metrics] //=> returns array [ 'temperature' ]
  if (!Array.isArray(stats)) stats = [stats] //> returns array [ 'min', 'max', 'average' ]


  let statistics = []

/**** refactor opportunity for nested for of loops ****/
  for (let metric of metrics) {
    for (let stat of stats) {
      try {
        let value = calculateStatsForMetric(stat, metric, measure)

        if (value) {
          statistics.push({
            metric: metric,
            stat: stat,
            value: value
          })
        }
      } catch (err) {
        return err
      }
    }
  }

  return statistics
}
```

Comment: If you really want to consider all permutations of metric+stat, you're going to need to do that (or something equivalent to that). What is it about the nesting that bothers you?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thank you for this insight, Benjamin. could you please post an answer so I can visualize the code better?

Comment: @Jonca33 - Note that what Benjamin's doing is still nested loops. The loops are just in `flatMap` and `map`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thank you for your time, I'm just trying to learn if there are better practices to take here in terms of writing in a more elegant way.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm struggling to conceptualize Benjamin's answer as a body text. Could you please post as an answer?

Comment: @Jonca33 - It's basically [this](https://pastebin.com/pxuAjJfd).

Comment: Side note: I'd strongly recommend not *returning* errors. Just let the error propagate through the exception mechanism as usual. (E.g., just remove that `try`/`catch` block entirely.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you very much. I've never used `flatMap` before. Based on my code, what would be passed as `Boolean` for `filter(Boolean)`?

Comment: @Jonca33 - He's using the built-in [`Boolean` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) so that `filter` has something to call. It's basically the same as `.filter(value => !!value)`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sounds good. I'll remove the `try/catch`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it currently errors: `calculateStatForMetric is not defined` is this on me or is it something missing on the suggested refactor? `calculateStatForMetric` was working as expected on my code example.

Comment: @Jonca33 - It's a typo in Benjamin's comment. Your function is called `calculateStatsForMetric` (note the `s` on the end of `Stats`).

Comment: you both taught me amazing advanced things today. thank you very much 

Comment: @T.J.Crowder one last thing. The reason I had `try/catch` was because since this is a Node server I wanted to send a `res.status()` back from the server... Without `catch` the server will just go `500` with no explanation for the user... Thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like you're using Express or similar and handling a server request via `app.get` or similar. In general, handle errors at the highest level you can (unless you have a strong reason for doing something else). In this case, that would be in your `app.get` (etc.) handler, the code that's calling `pleaseRefactorMe` and probably other things as well. `try { pleaseRefactorMe(/*..*/); doThis(); doThat(); } catch (error) { writeFullErrorToLogForDebugging(error); res.status(/*...*/); }`.

Comment: that's precisely right I have an express route checking for `if (!metrics || !stats) {
    res.status(412).send('metrics, stats is required')
    res.end()
  }` Which now no longer catches the error. It goes straight to 500. Are you suggesting to use `try/catch` on this route?

Comment: Right. That's the entry point to the JavaScript code, so it's the highest level where you can handle it, which is the default choice unless you have a reason for handling errors lower down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, always pass arrays in, methods usually shouldn't do this sort of input validation in JavaScript. Also don't throw in `calculateStatsForMetric`, if you have throwing code there wrap it in a try/catch and return a falsey value.

Now, you can use higher order array methods like [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

- Take each metric

  - For each metric
  - Take each stat (this calls for a flatMap on a map)
  - Calculate a function on it
  - Keep truthy values (this calls for a filter)

Or in code:

```
export const refactored = (measure, metrics, stats) => 
  metrics.flatMap(metric => stats.map(stat => ({
    metric,
    stat,
    value: calculateStatsForMetric(stat, metric, measure)
  }))).filter(o => o.value);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explanation Benjamin!

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to use `forEach` -

```
let statistics = [];
metrics.forEach(m => {
  stats.forEach(s => {
    let value = calculateStatsForMetric(s, m, measures);
    if (value) {
      statistics.push({
        metric: m,
        stat: s,
        value: value
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: That is definitely simpler and a step ahead of what I had. Thank you very much